# Getting Records with Min Max Value on Grouped in Single Table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

The table looks like this:

Existing Table:

table_1
[image]

Desired Result:

table_1
[image]

I have been able to get result like the following using this code:
[image]

table_1
[image]

But I would like to get minimum and maximum value on 'trans' row and their corresponding value on 'rate' row, "Grouped By date" on Single Table as following.

table_1
[image]

Comment: Note: text is far preferable to images for showing us what you want. It's relatively easy to try out your code, to generate sample data, etc, if we can select the actual text out of the question, instead of just having images. I believe someone had edited your original question to properly format the text provided; if that's the same as your images, you may want to [roll back](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/224787/revisions) to that. See [this answer on the Meta site](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2642/116653) for more info.

Comment: @RDFozz Yes I did and he replaced text with images.I was able to create sample table with data at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d55b5/8)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I've reduced a bit your sample data by entering only the first 10 rows.

```
create table tbl (id int, dt date, code text, trans text, rate int);

insert into tbl values
(1, '20181201', 'AAA', '2018120101', 399),
(2, '20181201', 'BBB', '2018120102', 244),
(3, '20181201', 'AAA', '2018120103', 400),
(4, '20181201', 'AAA', '2018120104', 397),
(5, '20181202', 'AAA', '2018120201', 395),
(6, '20181202', 'AAA', '2018120202', 405),
(7, '20181202', 'AAA', '2018120203', 399),
(8, '20181202', 'DDD', '2018120204', 355),
(9, '20181202', 'AAA', '2018120205', 402),
(10, '20181202', 'AAA', '2018120206', 403);
```

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by t0.code, t0.dt) as id,
    t0.code,
    t0.dt,
    min_trans,
    t1.rate as min_rate,
    max_trans,
    t2.rate as max_rate
from
    (select   code, dt, min(trans) min_trans, max(trans) max_trans
     from     tbl
     group by code, dt) t0
join
    tbl t1
    on t1.code = t0.code
    and t1.trans = t0.min_trans
join
    tbl t2
    on t2.code = t0.code
    and t2.trans = t0.max_trans;
```

> ```
> id | code | dt         | min_trans  | min_rate | max_trans  | max_rate
> -: | :--- | :--------- | :--------- | -------: | :--------- | -------:
>  1 | AAA  | 2018-12-01 | 2018120101 |      399 | 2018120104 |      397
>  2 | AAA  | 2018-12-02 | 2018120201 |      395 | 2018120206 |      403
>  3 | BBB  | 2018-12-01 | 2018120102 |      244 | 2018120102 |      244
>  4 | DDD  | 2018-12-02 | 2018120204 |      355 | 2018120204 |      355
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cb9bb5222d7fcf8dc9d8f1e33dc99981)*

The first sub-query calculates MIN and MAX trans value grouped by code and date.

```
from
    (select   code, dt, min(trans) min_trans, max(trans) max_trans
     from     tbl
     group by code, dt) t0
```

Then you can join twice your original table using code and max/min trans value fetched by the first sub-query.

```
join
    tbl t1
    on t1.code = t0.code
    and t1.trans = t0.min_trans
join
    tbl t2
    on t2.code = t0.code
    and t2.trans = t0.max_trans;
```

Adding a WHERE clause you can filter the final result by code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a magic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query :

```
WITH 
get_rate(d, min, max) AS (
SELECT t.date, min(t.trans), max(t.trans)
FROM test AS t 
WHERE t.code = 'AAA'
GROUP BY t.date
),
get_min(min, min_rate) AS (
SELECT distinct g.d, t.rate
FROM get_rate AS g JOIN test AS t ON g.min = t.trans
),
get_max(max, max_rate) AS (
SELECT distinct g.d, t.rate
FROM get_rate AS g JOIN test AS t ON g.max = t.trans
)
SELECT g.d, g.min, gmin.min_rate, g.max, gmax.max_rate
FROM get_rate AS g JOIN get_min AS gmin ON g.d = gmin.min JOIN get_max AS gmax    
ON g.d = gmax.max
ORDER BY g.d;
```

Comment: Hi welcome to the site. Thanks for your answer but it would be even better to explain how it works